# Getting submitted form value for confirmation page

Tags: php

to descibe simply, I've 3 php files- form.php, save.php & confirm.php

form.php is a general form having

```
<form id="form" name="form" method="post" action= 'save.php' ><form>
```

save.php is for updating SQL by insert command

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO database (name, age, sex, id) VALUES ('$name', '$age', '$sex', '$id')";
```

I'm also using header same page to redirect after save

```
header('Location: confirm.php');
```

Now what I'm expecting When people submit form, data will save to SQL & redirect to confirm.php where they can see their submitted data.

Its redirecting after save but I can't figure out the way to getting submitted data on confirm.php , I've tried to use $_SESSION but page is getting blank. I'd be great If I can pass submitted form's `$id` to confirm.php with $_SESSION or someting so can I can call `$id` from confirm.php & get the data. Please suggest how to do that.

Comment: SQL-Injection alert!!! You can either store the value in a session and pick it up on confirm.php orpass using header('Location: confirm.php?x=y');

Comment: Use Select Query on Confirm.php page to fetch data from database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get inserted ID through `$id = mysqli_insert_id();`

and pass `header('Location: confirm.php?id='.$id);`

and get details through this id.

in confirm.php `$_REQUEST['id'];`

Answer (score 0):

In the new form you have to do this as early as possible.  This gets the session values.

```
if(!isset($_SESSION))
   session_start();
```

To get the $id in the form, you have to either pass it as a param or save it in the session like so

```
$_SESSION['id']= $id;
```

Comment: I've tried that before, But I don't know why page is getting blank each time. Is there any conflict between update SQL, session_start() and calling header() from same page?

Comment: It works for everybody else.  I still think you are doing it too late.  The session capture has to be done before emitting the page header.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommand you to use AJAX submission to refresh the container after the POST and retrieve the submitted data.

If you do not want to use JavaScript, the best way to do this is to store the ID of the new submission and retrieve it on retrieve it on your confirm.php action.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. 2nd part of your suggestion is good. Mohit maru gave some solution works good. :-)